# Get part of URL with regular expression

Tags: regex

Can anyone tell me why this is not working? I just want to get test.jpg from the url

```
$html = 'this/large/test.jpg)';
$str = $html;
preg_match('/\/large\/(\d+)\)/',$str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Instead of regexes, use [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url)

Comment: 'this/large/test.jpg)' looks a little unusual for a URL. `$html` is an odd name for its variable, too. Is this real code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `\d` matches decimals (ie `[0-9]`) and `test.jpg` is not.

Try `preg_match('/\/large\/(.+)\)/',$str,$matches);`.

Answer (score 1):

`\d` matches only digits (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#105924)). Use `(.+)` instead.